# View not using it's class code?

Tags: ios, swift, class, view

I have a view that exist over my main view. I have given this view a class that's named DataView which I then later give a var initialiser in my main views code as:

```
var dataView2 = DataView()
```

After this I try to make this view disappear in the start of the app. like this.

```
class DataView UIView{
    func visibility(_ visible: Bool){
        self.alpha = visible ? 1 : 0
        print("data pls disappear",alpha)
        //I get alpha 0.0 from this but the view does not disappear.
    }
}

class ViewController:UIViewController{
    var dataView2 = DataView()

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        dataView2.visibility(false)
   }
}
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have created this DataView on storyboard but you have not created reference to DatView in ViewController. Please create reference to DataView in your viewController like below and link it to UIView on Storyboard since the view created on storyboard requires the reference. Hope this answers your question.

```
@IBOutlet weak var dataView2: DataView!
```